# Conditional Merge in R Data Frame using a String as a search

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am prepping a database for plotting in `ggplot` where I will plot a large `geom_point()` plot. I would like one set of point to stand out and was thinking of making a dummy column so that I could use that column as a color variable as in:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x-x,y-y,color=color)
colors=c("yes"="orange2", "no"="grey")
scale_color_manual(values=colors)
```

to make the dummy column I wanted to do as follows:

```
df$color <- "no"
```

to set the default color, and then use a grep substitute to make a highlight color.

```
df$color[grep("string", df$V1, ignore.case=T),] < "yes"
```

where `V1` is a column that contains the string I would like to substitute. Although I would love some suggestions on how to get the substitution I would also be interested in learning about a more direct coloring method that would involve highlighting data of a particular value.

thanks

Comment: your approach seems reasonable to me, you could combine color to something like (untested) `df$color <- with(df, ifelse(grepl("string", V1, ignore.case = TRUE), "yes", "no")`.

Comment: thanks chase - your method works great. I forgot to mention that my method was giving an error message: incorrect number of dimensions. I meant to ask how to resolve that but your method works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `grepl`. I am using the `mtcars` data set for illustrative purposes. Say you want `Merc` to stand out. You can call

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = grepl('Merc', rownames(mtcars)))) +
  scale_colour_manual("Merc", values = c('black', 'red'))
```